# l3prop - getting an entry inside a macro fails

Tags: expl3, l3prop

I the following example I defined two new macros `\UseLength` and `\xUseLength`. Both macros shall put back the stored value of the key in the input stream. The macro `\UseLength` works as expected. The second one first tests if the key exists. However if I use the macro `\xUseLength` I get the flaw:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_long:D 
l.30 foo \hspace{\xUseLength{dim}{width}}
                                          bar
```

Why does the example fail?

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_md_dim_prop
\prop_new:N \l_md_skip_prop

\prop_put:Nnx \l_md_dim_prop { width } { 2cm }
\prop_put:Nnx \l_md_skip_prop { above } { 1cm~plus~0.2cm }
\NewDocumentCommand \UseLength { m m }
 {
   \prop_get:cn { l_md_#1_prop } { #2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \xUseLength { m m }
 {
      \prop_get:cnNTF
      { l_md_#1_prop } { #2 }
      \l_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
      {\msg_term:n {no~entry~in~prop}~1cm }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
foo \hspace{\UseLength{dim}{width}} bar


%foo \hspace{\xUseLength{dim}{width}} bar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is writing fully expandable functions (which is rather tricky and often not really the best approach). `\hspace` is looking for a dimension and that has to come without anything stopping expansion, such as assignments. Thus stuff like `\prop_get:cnNTF` is not usable at all. What remains are the fairly slow things like `\prop_get:cn`. In addition one has to check for

- is the property list used actually a property list?
- is the key inside the property list? (if not we get an empty value, so for some applications that isn't even an answerable question)

So here is something that "kind of" works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_md_dim_prop
\prop_new:N \l_md_skip_prop

\prop_put:Nnx \l_md_dim_prop { width } { 2cm }
\prop_put:Nnx \l_md_skip_prop { above } { 1cm~plus~0.2cm }
\NewDocumentCommand \UseLength { m m }
 {
   \prop_get:cn { l_md_#1_prop } { #2}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nTF { f }  % we need that variant below

\NewDocumentCommand \xUseLength { m m }
 {
     \prop_if_exist:cTF { l_md_#1_prop }  % we need to check this as \prop_get:cn does not create a property list but just blows up
        {
          \tl_if_empty:fTF                % return value is empty but only if we do "f" expansion
            {  \prop_get:cn { l_md_#1_prop } { #2}  }
            {  1cm 
               \msg_term:n {no~entry~in~#1~ for~ #2}
            }
            {  \prop_get:cn { l_md_#1_prop } { #2} } 
       }
      { 1cm 
         \msg_term:n {undefined~ property~ store:~ #1}
      }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
foo \hspace{\UseLength{dim}{width}} bar     \par
foo \hspace{\xUseLength{dim}{width}} bar    \par
foo \hspace{\xUseLength{dim}{xwidth}} bar   \par
foo \hspace{\xUseLength{xdim}{width}} bar   \par
\end{document}
```

The error recovery is still questionable as it may happen at a point where it still blows up, but for situations like `\hspace` it would do.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this as `\hspace` requires a number after (`f`-type) expansion, and `\xUseLength` will not yield a number as it contains an assignment (`\prop_get:cnNTF` is supposed to assign to `\l_tmpa_tl`). On the other hand, `\UseLength` is `f-`type expandable as there is no assignment inside it.

Note that as TeX is looking for a number here, `\protected` status makes no difference to expansion.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve the issue? A simple `\UseLength` doesn't allow any package specific messages.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It's an expansion context: you'll need to use an expandable error if you need one here. Expandable messages are also possible (Bruno has some ideas), but we've not added that.

Comment: I posted an example in the chat using `\quark_if_no_value:nTF` which seems to work.